# R / Python confidence interval

Tags: python, r, confidence-interval

Just trying to figure out a R -> Python thing: Why are these two items not giving the same results?

Calculating 95% confidence interval for sample data with mean = 65, s = 22, n = 121.

R:
`tsum.test(n.x=121, mean.x=65, s.x=22)`

gives 95% confidence interval of 
`61.04014 68.95986`

Python:
`stats.norm.interval(alpha=0.95, loc=65, scale=22/np.sqrt(121))`

gives 95% confidence interval of 
`(61.080072030919894, 68.9199279690801)`

I thought that these should be identical results, or am I not using the appropriate equivalent Python function for R's `tsum.test` ?

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation I can see that I was wrong to assume to use `stats.norm` for this.

`scipy.stats.t` allows for the degree of freedom calculation that R's `tsum.test` is doing automatically:

`stats.t.interval(alpha = 0.95, df = 121-1, loc = 65, scale= 22/np.sqrt(121))`
returns
`(61.04013918989445, 68.95986081010555)`

which round at 5 decimal points to the answers given by `tsum.test` in R.

The general function I am using, if helpful, is this:

`````
def get_conf_interval_from_sample(n, mean, sigma, alpha = 0.95) :
    """Get confidence interval from sample data with sample of n, mean, sigma, where df = n-1
    Equivalent to getting confidence interval using t.test / tsum.test in R"""
    df = n-1
    scale = sigma / np.sqrt(n)
    return stats.t.interval(alpha=alpha, df=df, loc=mean, scale=scale)````
`````